# Would it be possible to have light that is a cross between a laser and a none laser light?

Tags: visible-light, laser

Normally light moves through all three dimensions which is why it's intensity at any particular point depends on the inverse of the distance squared.  For practical purposes we can say that laser light only moves in one direction and that its intensity at any point that is in line with the laser light is independent of distance.  Would it be possible to have a light that for practical purposes could be said to move through a flat plane instead of all three dimensions of space so that the intensity of light at any point along that plane would depend on the inverse of the distance instead of the inverse of the distance squared?  How would such light be produced?

Comment: No, light does not go as $\frac{1}{r^2}$ . That's only for a point source. No, laser light does not "move" in only one direction.  Have you seen a diffraction pattern?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because all of its assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, One of the magic properties of laser light is its _spatial coherence_.  That basically means, it appears as if it emanates from an infinitessimal _point source_.

Comment: @AndersGustafson Just use a cylinder diverging lens on a laser beam. Then you will have (in the geometrical optics approximation under the assumption that the original beam was parallel) the kind of decay behaviour you are interested in. (Of course $r$ is now the cylinder radius from the axis, not the distance from a single point).

Comment: @jameslarge Yes it's got spatial coherence. No, it does not act as though it comes from a point source.

Answer (score 1):

> **For practical purposes we can say that laser light only moves in one direction and that its intensity at any point that is in line with the laser light is independent of distance.**

That is not the case, depending on what exactly you mean by "for practical purposes".

If you are using a laser beam to illuminate a target that is larger than the divergence of the beam at the distance of the target, then all the beam's light is received by the target.

However if your "intensity at any point" on the target refers to points that are smaller than the beam divergence, the intensity should follow an inverse square law.

In other words, light from a laser beam follows the same laws of physics as light from an incandescent light bulb.

A [laser beam directed at the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment) might have a diameter of 7 km on the moon. This is important if your target is a [105 cm reflector](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LRO/multimedia/lroimages/lroc-20100413-apollo15-LRRR.html#.VkHPSbEleUk) and you are observing using a 3m telescope

Answer (score 0):

There are two different answers which might be "reasonable" to this question.

Taking your question very literally, laser light, by definition, is light amplified by stimulated emission from a pumped gain medium with population inversion. In *practice*, one of the easiest ways of exploiting amplification by spontaneous emission is through multiple passes of light through a slab of gain medium. But it doesn't need to be like this; think of the following thought experiment.

We have a big sphere of gain medium, with some means of pumping it so that the raised states are uniformly spread across the whole thing (footnote 1). Then you have a fluorophore at the sphere's center: it relaxes. The stimulated emission will add to the emitted photon and the system's output will be a spherical wave, with dipolar symmetry.

So laser light doesn't have to be tightly directional, although it often is in practice.

This leads into a second possible interpretation of your question: whether one can make light of any degree of coherence. The answer to this is a resounding yes. The simplest possible outcome to the thought experiment above is a spherical coherent state.  But lasers can make quite *incoherent* light depending on the detailed physics of their gain mediums. Nowadays spontaneous emission is used to make even very broadband light. Look up the notion of a [supercontinuum or white light laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinuum).

**[1]** You might use a very, very bright pulse of pump light, some "distribution network" of transparent channels ferrying the pump light throughout the sphere or choose mediums like erbium doped glass with stupendously long lifetimes (milliseconds) to help you achieve this.